# Binding texture memory to a GPU allocated matrix

Tags: memory, matrix, cuda, textures

I created a float point matrix on the GPU of size (p7P_NXSTATES)x(p7P_NXTRANS) like so:

```
// Special Transitions
// Host pointer to array of device pointers
float **tmp_xsc = (float**)(malloc(p7P_NXSTATES * sizeof(float*)));
// For every alphabet in scoring profile...
for(i = 0; i < p7P_NXSTATES; i++)
{
    // Allocate memory for device for every alphabet letter in protein sequence
    cudaMalloc((void**)&(tmp_xsc[i]), p7P_NXTRANS * sizeof(float));
    // Copy over arrays
    cudaMemcpy(tmp_xsc[i], gm.xsc[i], p7P_NXTRANS * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
// Copy device pointers to array of device pointers on GPU (matrix)
float **dev_xsc;
cudaMalloc((void***)&dev_xsc, p7P_NXSTATES * sizeof(float*));
cudaMemcpy(dev_xsc, tmp_xsc, p7P_NXSTATES * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

This memory, once copied over to the GPU, is never changed and is only read from. Thus, I've decided to bind this to texture memory. Problem is that when working with 2D texture memory, the memory being bound to it is really just an array that uses offsets to function as a matrix.

I'm aware I need to use cudaBindTexture2D() and cudaCreateChannelDesc() to bind this 2D memory in order to access it as such

> tex2D(texXSC,x,y)

-- but I'm just not sure how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot bind arrays of pointers to textures. You can either create a CUDA array and copy data to it from linear source memory, or use pitched linear memory directly bound to a texture. But an array of pointers will not work.

Comment: Darn, well I guess that works too. I can just simplify my code by hiding it behind a single macro as I did for the 1D texture memory. Any chance I can get an example of how to use this function you mentioned with the above code.

Comment: To repeat my answer: you can't use anything I mentioned with your code becuase your code is allocating arrays of device pointers and those cannot be used with any sort of texture operations.